# Auto sizing two block elements

Tags: html, css, position

I'd like to accomplish the following. (**which seems impossible**)

Let's say I have a container block that has fixed height and width. Within that block, there are two other blocks. (The orange and blue blocks)

[image: two blocks with children]

**I want the orange block to resize its height depending on the height of the blue block**. The blue block is positioned absolute at the bottom of the container block.

**How would I do this with CSS only?** (and with as little as HTML as possible)

---

Little fiddle that shows my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/uK64u/2/

---

As per request, one of many attempts:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div id="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
}

#orange
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#blue
{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This fails, as the blue block overlaps the orange one instead of resizing its height.

Comment: At first glance this seems pretty basic. Can you post the HTML and CSS you've tried?

Comment: To clarify, are you planning on displaying any content in the top block, or just the bottom one?

Comment: @Serlite - Yes, the top block should display content. It must not be obstructed by the bottom block.

Comment: Since the overall block container has fixed dimensions, what would you desire to happen if the blue block is too tall to both display both its content and the orange block's?

Comment: @Serlite - That's out of scope of the question. I'll most probably cap the height of the blue block. But until that cap has been reached, the orange block should compensate for the changing height of the blue block.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe CSS3 Flexbox would be useful?

Comment: @sheriffderek - Why not? I'm describing a desired layout / behaviour.

Comment: Is it absolutely imperative that the top element resize as the bottom one increases in height? If the bottom element will never overlap the top content, the viewer would never be able to tell if the top element is actually resizing, or if it is only behind the bottom element. (Unless there's a particular visual effect you desire that isn't mentioned?)

Comment: What is in the orange box. Why is this outside of the scope of the question?

Comment: @Serlite - It is imperative. :)

Comment: @sheriffderek - The orange block contains normal inline text. The amount of text is not important. I'll just have the orange block display a scrollbar as soon as the orange block isn't heigh enough for  displaying its total contents.

Comment: That is very important stuff that changes how we will answer this. CSS can't just say, if this then that with - well, but in this situation - etc etc. CSS is a declarative language. You have to make all of the use cases, and then make rules for each scenario.

Comment: @sheriffderek - Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by giving the orange a `position:relative` and the text in the blue background a `position:absolute`. See the [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/G2qak/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="box-outer">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-outer {
    border:1px solid #222;
    background-color:orange;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
 }
 p {
    background-color:blue;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

I've ***RE-EDITTED*** my fiddle..lol..

Comment: I'm afraid that would still block content that goes into the orange block. The blue and orange blocks need to be separated.

Comment: I've edited the fiddle. You'll have a orange div now with a height auto. and the blue div can be capped as you mentioned in the comments

Comment: Ah I see what you mean

Comment: You're biting into it, aren't you? ;) But, I'm afraid it's not the desired behaviour. The wrapper (container) should be of fixed height, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/uK64u/2/

Comment: yikes, I'll keep brainstorming, but I'm afraid that is about as far as CSS can go. All related css properties that are relevant to positioning are already applied. :(

Comment: If I were you I woudl apply what we have so far (it does resize ) and then since you were thinking of capping the blue anyway, give that much cap to a margin-bottom to the orange. Or use JQuery resize()

Comment: Feels like giving up for me. :(

Comment: lol. Not really man, It just seems like a lot more work than you should afford for front end development. Unless this is for a personal project or something like that

Comment: I still need to know the solution to this.. :p

Answer (score 0):

Okay...well, here's an idea on how you might achieve this behaviour, though it somewhat hearkens back to the days of table-based layouts. With this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="orange">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    display:table;
}
.orange {
    background:#AAA;
    height:100%;
    display:table-row;
}
.blue {
    background:#CCC;
    display:table-row;
}
.blue .content {
    max-height:500px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

I think this gets the effect you're describing. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDpr2/4/) demonstrating it. Try adding content to the bottom element - if you inspect elements with some web developer tools, you'll see the top element is actually resizing.

I also took the liberty of applying a limit to the height of the bottom element's content (and used `overflow:scroll`, hence the extra scroll bars), though you can certainly remove that to change how you deal with excessive content.

Comment: Close! The thing is, the container should be of fixed height. Now, the table styled div grows with its content.

Comment: Yep, that's why I added in the `max-height` on the bottom element. At this point, it becomes relevant to know what you want to happen when the combined content heights exceed the container height - which you originally felt was not in the question's scope.

Comment: I see. Well, when the combined content height exceeds the container height, the bottom half needs to show a scrollbar.

Comment: If the top content is of variable amount (making it unknown when the bottom content will overlap it), then I'm not sure at the moment. The `max-height` in the Fiddle (which I added to my answer) works if setting a defined cutoff height is permissible, though.

Comment: The thing here I think is the 'fixed' part. There is no way anything would work with fixed while being relative to something else. The "re-sizing" part of the orange makes it's dependent element relative so that it changes with it